# What's the difference between GoogleAuth.signIn and GoogleAuth.grantOfflineAccess?

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-oauth, google-authentication

We have an application that uses the response.code from GoogleAuth.grantOfflineAccess to do some sign in stuff with our server. What I'm trying to do is change grantOfflineAccess to signIn so I can specify the "ux_mode" as 'redirect'... but the response you get back from the two is vastly different.

grantOfflineAccess returns a "code" property, but signIn returns a lot of other stuff. Is there an equivalent to the "code" property in the signIn response?